# How can I tell if the object is scaled up or scaled down?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Not starting but finished scaling up or down.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Scaling : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToScale;
    public GameObject lookAtTarget;
    public float duration = 1f;
    public Vector3 minSize;
    public Vector3 maxSize;
    public bool scaleUp = false;
    public Coroutine scaleCoroutine;

    public void Inits()
    {
        objectToScale.transform.localScale = minSize;
    }

    public IEnumerator scaleOverTime(GameObject targetObj, Vector3 toScale, float duration, Camera objectToScaleCamera)
    {
        float counter = 0;
        Vector3 startScaleSize = targetObj.transform.localScale;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, counter / duration);

            if (scaleUp)
            {
                var lookPos = lookAtTarget.transform.position - objectToScale.transform.position;
                lookPos.y = 0;
                var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
                objectToScale.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(objectToScale.transform.rotation, rotation, counter / duration);
            }
            else
            {
                var lookPos = lookAtTarget.transform.position - objectToScale.transform.position;
                lookPos.y = 0;
                var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(objectToScaleCamera.transform.forward);//SwitchCameras.GetCurrentCamera().transform.forward);//Camera.main.transform.forward);
                objectToScale.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(objectToScale.transform.rotation, rotation, counter / duration);
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator scaleOverTime(GameObject targetObj, Vector3 toScale, float duration, float rotationSpeed)
    {
        float counter = 0;
        Vector3 startScaleSize = targetObj.transform.localScale;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, counter / duration);

            targetObj.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to know the state of the object if it's scaled up or scaled down. Maybe using a public static bool ?

So in other script I will be able to check for example if(Scaling.scaledUp == true) then I know the object finished scaling up. Same for down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to check if objectToScale.transform.localScale <= minSize or if objectToScale.transform.localScale >= maxSize?  All of those are public variables, so a standard 'if' statement should do the trick, but you can also make those inline properties to increase readability.  As long as the scale is uniform, you can use any of the three axes to do the checks.

Comment: You can't compare vector3 like >= so I will have to check each axes x,y,z.

Comment: @yochile if its uniform scale you could compair the magnitudes, if its not you'll have to compair each component individually

Comment: also @yochile consider that in case its not uniformly scaled it could be scaled up along one axis but scaled down on another. thats why you cant simply check wheter a vector is greater or less as in general terms it only makes sense for the magnitude.